# DocuSign REST API - create envelope id but error: Authentication fail

Tags: docusignapi

REST Request accepted by Docusign, create envelope and transaction id. But responds with Authentication fail for recipient.

Response: INVALIDAUTHENTICATIONSETUP Authentication is not setup correctly for the recipient.

```
response code:
  "pyMessage": "Authentication is not setup correctly for the 
  "pyErrorCode": "INVALIDAUTHENTICATIONSETUP"
  "pyStatusMessage": "the HTTP response code of 400 indicated a client error. The response data may contain a reason.",
  "pyStatus": "Fail",
  "pyHTTPResponseCode": "400",
  "pyStatusValue": "Fail: Unexpected HTTP 400 Response code"
```

**JSON Header**

URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1be73a9a-a25a-4221-8188-385a6a815b5b/envelopes/101

Set header "X-DocuSign-Authentication" to value

```
{
"Username":"b037ea2d-7fff-4974-bbad-**********",
"Password":"******",
"IntegratorKey":"d84fd933-e69b-49fc-b67a-**********"
}
```

and json body:

https://www.scribd.com/document/317788272/Request-Json

**DocuSign API log**

File: 08_OK_ExecuteLoggedApiBusinessLogic.txt

```
enter code here 
Host: demo.docusign.net
x-docusign-clienttransactionid: T24120121904615319199
x-docusign-diagnostics: {storedProcedureEventLogThreshold:300}
x-docusign-timetrack: REQ_SENT,2016-07-08T15:13:48.116Z;REST0_Start,2016-07-08T15:13:48.0389520Z
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-ClientTransactionId: T24120121904615319199
X-DocuSign-TimeTrack: REQ_SENT,2016-07-08T15:13:48.116Z;;REST0_Start,2016-07-08T15:13:48.0389520Z;REST0_End,2016-07-08T15:13:48.0701940Z

{}
```

But still response has status code 400 with error "Authentication is not setup correctly for the recipient"

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have no idea, but I guess it would have to do something with the "authentication setup", so please share that (edit the question)

Comment: thanks for reply, I added more details. your guidance would appreciate...

Comment: Please remember to upvote all useful answers (including to other people's questions) and "check" (select) the best answers to your own questions. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Larry, I was giving sms authenication tag empty in first error, due to which I was getting

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create an envelope then the right URL to use is

POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1be73a9a-a25a-4221-8188-385a6a815b5b/envelopes/

Not https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1be73a9a-a25a-4221-8188-385a6a815b5b/envelopes/101

You may also want to look at the [recipe for sending an envelope](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email).

Also, you should protect your integration key and your password. So please make a new integrator key and delete the one that you have shared on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for direction. Finally it worked after removing sms authentication. Based on this [link](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/16)  in Demo account there is no sms authontication enable.  It would help if this get documented in docusign REST API help. Thanks to All.

Comment: @DuttuDolphin, I just created a new demo account and was able to do SMS authentication. My guess is that your SMS authentication request was not done correctly. Try to send an envelope from the web tool and request SMS confirmation. If it works, then your account has the feature and the problem was with your Envelopes: create call.

Comment: Hey Larry, I was giving sms authenication tag empty in first error, due to which I was getting  "Authentication is not setup correctly for the recipient" . After proper setup, sms authentication worked. For other Here is  json https://www.scribd.com/document/318227201/Working-Json

Comment: @DuttuDolphin, Thank you, that's very helpful.